# Unicode strings or unicode_literals python 2

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

I am relatively new to python, and I am working in an application that will support in the end English, Spanish and German. I want to plan i18n in advance, and I've read that the best approach is the sandwich one, in which the application uses unicode strings everywhere and we only decode/encode upon user input/output. The question is how to do this, do I have to prepend a 'u' to every single string in my app? is unicode_literals from __future__ package an option? There is no intention to port this application to python 3 in the near future.

Comment: Go ahead and import `unicode_literals` if it makes your life easier - there's no law reserving it for porting purposes. Consider though that other people looking over your code may get confused.